# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' on line 1098 >

Tags: php, parse, syntax-error

Galera, tenho um function.php que termina assim:

```
// Clear Helper/s
/* **************************************************************************************************** */

function n_clear() {
    echo "<div class='clear'></div>";
}
```

Ele funciona perfeitamente.

Só que quando eu adicione essas linhas:

```
// LEIA MAIS
add_filter('the_content_more_link', 'filter_more_link');

function filter_more_link( $link ) {
    return ' <a class="read-more" href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '" title="Continue lendo '.get_the_title().'">Continue lendo '.get_the_title().'...</a>';
}
```

Ele mostra o seguinte erro: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' on line 1098 >`

Alguém sabe resolver?

Comment: Isto é wordpress? esse arquivo functions.php é de algum plugin ou é nativo do wordpress?

Comment: Tem certeza que é esse arquivo?

Comment: O que está na linha 1098 ? E qual o ficheiro indicado pelo `parse error` ?

Comment: Talvez haja aspas não escapadas no título ou no permalink de algum registro.

Comment: Qual o arquivo que o `parse error` está especificando? esta sua linha de código está correta!